# Invalid Field for SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject

I have 2 fields that I'd like to use in my VFP.

[image]

Valores_ativos_e_passivos__c is working fine, but when I try to use Ativos_e_passivos__c I receive the Invalid field for SObject error. What am I missing?

**Working FINE:**

```
<table>
                <h4>
                   Ativos e passivos
                </h4> 
                {!KYC_Form__c.Valores_ativos_e_passivos__c}
 </table>
```

**NOT working:**

```
<table>
                <h4>
                   Ativos e passivos
                </h4> 
                {!KYC_Form__c.Ativos_e_passivos__c}
</table>
```

I've tried "KYC_Form__r.Ativos_e_Passivos__c" but the error still the same. The problem can be the type of the field?

Comment: Are you have field access for that field?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's visible to all profiles

Comment: In the org where you are experiencing this issue, did you create the field in the org, or deploy the field from a different org into this one? This issue usually appears after you deploy a new field to an org. Field Level Security for the field does not get deployed along with the field, so you need to set FLS manually in each org you deploy it to (permission sets can contain FLS and be deployed, though it is a pain to initially assign permission sets to users).

Comment: I've created the field in the org that I'm experiencing the issue... The field is visible to all profiles

Comment: Have you queried the field `Ativos_e_passivos__c` or how could you please share more about the controller of this page?

Comment: Are you sure your IDE is connected to the correct org?

Comment: I've created both of the fields at the same time, the only difference between them is the type of field. One I can use in my VFP and the other one I still receiving the same error

Comment: I've created another Rich Text field named Test__c and I received the same error in my VFP.

Comment: You can use VF tags to check if it works:

<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!KYC_Form__c. Ativos_e_passivos__c}" ></apex:outputText>